# Ruby on Rails: Adding a user for login to my existing app killed my index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, thinking-sphinx

I have an app that I've been developing that has so far only been a single user environment. I finally got to the point where I needed to add multi-user capabilities so I followed the railscast on [authlogic](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic) to get a simple login.

I then added a `has_many :items` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :items` and a `belongs_to :user` to the correct models. I then dropped the database and setup and then migrated it. I also added a `user_id` column to all my nested models.

After that, when I click on the "Create new item" link, I go to the new page and create a new item. When I go back to the item_index page, it's not showing up anymore. I can go to localhost/item/1 and see the record, so I know that it's being created, but when I try to view it in my item_index.html.erb it doesn't show up anymore.

Here's the basic loop that was working before I added the user. (It's rendering into a table)

```
<% for item in @items %>
    <%= link_to item.name, item %>
<% end %>
```

I imagine that the loop is what's wrong, but I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks

edit: Here's what's happening in my index method in my item controller:

```
   def index
     @items = Item.search params[:search]
     if @items.nil?
       @items = Item.all
     end
   end
```

I have the weird `if nil?` thing because I'm using thinking-sphinx and it was failing sometimes if the index was empty.

edit2:

If I change the index to have just

```
def index
   @items = Item.all
end
```

Everything shows up. So that means that it has to do with thinking sphinx messing with my render

edit3: in thinking-sphinx fashion, I did some things unrelated to it, and it magically works again.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking Sphinx is going to be returning an empty result set `[]`, when you try to iterate over this empty set you're not going to get any items shown.

To my knowledge, Thinking Sphinx will **never** return `nil` for a search result.

Perhaps try this instead:

```
if @items.empty?
  @items = Item.all
end
```

Comment: Also, I tried to do `for item in @items; item.name; end;` in the rails console and it said that I had a nil object when I didn't expect it. If I execute `Item.all` it shows my items.

Comment: @Reti: I've updated my answer to reflect your edits now. It should answer your question clearly.

Comment: If Item.search returns an array with nil entries in it, your index is out of sync with your database. Try re-indexing and restarting the sphinx daemon.